# Отображение компьютеров в сети в MacOS, используя Swift

Tags: swift, macos, mac, apple

Стоит задача Отобразить всех рабочих групп, компьютеров в сети и их ресурсов (папок, открытых для общего доступа, принтеров). Исходя из того, что имеется компьютер на MacOS и изучаю я по большей мере Swift, он и был выбран как язык для решения проблемы. Однако есть проблема в том, что я с данной сферой не знаком и не уверен, что вообще проблема решаема на данном языке. Если уверены, что это так, посоветуйте другой язык для решения. Заранее благодарю

Comment: Может быть, получить список компьютеров? Отобразить это довольно общее понятие.

Comment: ну да, в виде списка